# Ubuntu 17.10/18.04 Gnome stuck when I try to resize window screen

Tags: gnome, 17.10, 18.04

When I try to resize window, or try to work with two windows by using (Super key + left arrow and super key + right arrow) My OS hands and doesn't answer at all. Even NumLock's not working. I have changed drivers for Graphic card (used X.Org or prop drivers doesnt matter), but I had the same problem. 
Update
18.04 has the same problem

Comment: I have updated to 18.04 problem haven't gone

Comment: I have the same problem on stock Ubuntu 18.04